# Hibernate entity not getting indexed

Tags: hibernate-search

I am indexing Activity and metaentity:

Activity contains following field:

```
 @Table(name = "activity")
            @Indexed
            public class Activity implements java.io.Serializable {

            private Long id;
            private Date timeStamp;
            private User user;

         /*index metaentity inside activity.*/
            @IndexedEmbedded
            private Metaentity metaentityByEntity;
        }
```

Metaentity table contains followng fields:

```
      public class Metaentity implements java.io.Serializable {

            private Long id;
            @IndexedEmbedded
            private User userByOwner;
//when metaentity changes update activity entity inside the index
            @ContainedIn
            private Set<Activity> activitiesForProject = new HashSet<Activity>(0);

        }
```

In activity I want to index **metaentityByEntity** But when I create index activity index for metaentity is empty. I have no idea why this issue is coming.

Is it due to in Metaentity class I have specified @ContainedIn for **Set  of activitiesForProject** ?

Comment: You should also describe the mapping annotations. And it would be useful to see your test.

Comment: if I specify @indexembeded over user then user is getting indexed. but same is not getting applied to Metaentity.. :(